# How to install older version of statsmodels

Tags: statsmodels

Is there a way to install an older version of statsmodels? Such as using pip install statsmodels x.xx? I cant find any documentation on their website about this. Thanks

I've tried using the current version but encounter errors when running the code. if i use import statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA i get the following error

`statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have been removed in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA`

When i replace arima_model with arima.model other lines of code will not work such as

`` `      2 # Build Model ``
`3 model = ARIMA(train_data, order=(1,1,0))`
`----> 4 fitted = model.fit(disp=-1)`
`5 print(fitted.summary())`

`` TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'` ``

I'd like to revert the version of statsmodels so i can get the program to run

Comment: `pip install statsmodels==0.12.2` will install 0.12.2.  You can change this value for another version if needed. Note that older statsmodels will not work with the most recent scipy and pandas, so you might need older verions of these as well.